# Having only a numeric in an inputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf problem:
I want to an "inputText" to be only a numeric. For this I use  but it does not work.

When I fill the field with a word (for instance), no error message appears.

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="profil">
    <p:inputText  value="#{effectifBean.efCadre}" 
        validatorMessage="#{messages['content.msg']}" >
       <f:validateRegex pattern="[1-9]*" />
    </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean, you want to see the error message immediately once the key is pressed on the input and not only when the form is submitted? The code which you've posted so far should work fine, but it of course only shows the message once you submit the form.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Ideally I would like to have the error directly but at least if it works (but it doesn't at the moment) when the form is submitted it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

why you not use [inputMask](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf) if you know the number of char inside input ?

```
<p:inputMask value="#{effectifBean.efCadre}" mask="99999"/>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer I didn't know that. But the problem with that solution is (if I am correct) that when the user enter letters there is no error message, so this no the best for me I think.

Comment: @Fabaud which error do you want to display? With that there's no possibility directly to input any character. If user achieves to hack in some way the Primefaces client side stuff JSF will reject it if you have a destination `Integer` value at server side. There's a way also to display an error message and do what you want, but I think is worse user experience, isn't it?

Comment: Thx for your help. What I would like is something like that : when the user starts to input letters in the field an error message is displayed for advertising him. If it is not possible, an error message displayed when the user change of field.